# finding a general form for a series with known input/output

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find a general form for a series of numbers expressed with a variable $n$.
given the following input/output pairs:

- $n=1$: output = $1$
- $n=2$: output = $5$
- $n=3$: output = $12$
- $n=4$: output = $22$
- $n=5$: output = $35$

I found the following relationships, which suggest to me that there IS a formula for this, but I am not sure how to find/express it:

output2 - output1 = $4$, output3 - output2 = $7$, output4 - output3 = $10$... - so the difference in outputs grows by $3$.

Also, the series given by output-n is $0,3,9,18,30$ : 3 * 0, 3 * 1, 3 * 3, 3 * 6, 3 * 10 : 1-0 = 1, 3-1 = 2, 6-3 = 3, 10-6 = 4...

so clearly there is a connection between these numbers, but I am at a loss as to how to find/express it. My final answer needs to be in terms of $n$ (so for example $n(n+1)/2$ ).

Thanks!

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C12%2C22&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Such questions are not acceptable in this site. 'Opinon based' is  one of the reasons for closing a question.

Comment: @geetha290krm -- I'm not sure what you mean. Not only is this question not opinion based (indeed, it has a mathematically reasonable answer) but OP has clearly shown that they've put effort into thinking about the problem for themself. I have no idea why you think this question is not acceptable on this site

Comment: @geetha290krm -- you're being pedantic. It's clear from context that this sequence follows some kind of pattern, and OP is interested in the unique sequence which continues that pattern. Moreover, we have enough terms of the sequence given in order to find this pattern and pin down the rest (as my answer shows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

So, tl;dr, your sequence is the [pentagonal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number), and is given by the formula

$$
\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}
$$

The fastest way to see this is to type your sequence into [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C12%2C22%2C35&language=english&go=Search) and let the computer tell you what it is.

But what if you wanted to do it by hand? After all, you've done a lot of good work, and you're really close to solving it yourself!

Let's write $a_n$ for what you're calling "output-n". So $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 5$, $a_3 = 12$, and so on.

You had the idea of taking "finite differences", namely looking at $a_{n+1} - a_n$ (in the literature, you'll often see this written as $\Delta a_n$). These didn't immediately give a pattern, so you did it again, looking at finite differences *between* the finite differences! This is a *fantastic* idea, and (provided $a_n$ is a polynomial in $n$) will always get you to a closed form!

It's a bit involved to explain in this answer, but you can find resources by googling for the [calculus of finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). You've actually asked this at a particularly good time, because a youtuber recently released [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scQ51q_1nhw) explaining this exact technique! In fact, he uses *your exact sequence* as his example in the video!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot! :)

Comment: Happy to help ^_^